# Eta reduction for data modification

Tags: haskell, lambda

I get a warning to eta reduce the following lambda expression.

```
\(DataType arg1 arg2) -> DataType (modify arg1) arg2
```

The internet tells me eta-reducing means to leave out unnecessary lambdas.

```
map (\x -> fun x) list
map fun list
```

How is that applicable to the code above? Am I perhaps just missing a basic syntax for modifying data types?

Comment: I assume this is a warning from hlint? Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case you can't eta reduce it any further.  There is only a single argument to the lambda, namely `(DataType arg1 arg2)`.  These are not separate arguments, as indicated by the parentheses, but instead you are pattern matching on a constructor.  In reality, the compiler will reduce this expression to something more like

```
\arg -> case arg of
    DataType arg1 arg2 -> DataType (modify arg1) arg2
```

Here it is more clear that there is only one argument to the lambda, and it is not used in such a way that it can be reduced.  The main rule for reduction is when you have something like

```
\a b c -> f b a c
```

The `c` argument appears as the last term in the argument declaration and in the expression, so it can be dropped:

```
\a b -> f b a
```

Now, if we wanted to reduce this lambda we could define a higher order function

```
flip f a b = f b a
```

And write it as simply

```
flip f
```

(Note that `flip` already exists in `Prelude`).

Another rule you can apply is when dealing with the `$` operator.  Put simply, if you have something like

```
\a b c -> f a $ g b $ h c
```

Then you can first turn this into a composition:

```
\a b c -> (f a . g b . h) c
```

And now it is simple to drop the `c` argument

```
\a b -> f a . g b . h
```

And in general, you can usually swap `$`s for `.`s and drop the last argument.

Again, this doesn't apply in your case because your function only has 1 argument, and that argument is pattern matched on to pull out a constructor's arguments, then an entirely new value is reconstructed from it.